# How to convert from Hex to Decimal using only Integers in C

Tags: c, hex, decimal

I'm receiving the following data over a serial port: `<0x1b><0x2e><0x15>...`
Each value enclosed in `'<>'` is a single byte.
I require the third byte from the data so i do this:

```
int Length;
char Data[..];
Length = Data[2];
```

But the value of Length is 21 and not 15 because the value written in memory is hex.
How do i convert the decimal representation of 15 to decimal 15?

I've tried converting it to various types and so on..
But none of that works for me as i'm writing a driver and performance matters a lot.
I've looked over stackoverflow and other sites but all the given examples are with strings, none are with plain integers.

When i send it to the rest of the algorithm i run into issues as the algorithm expects 15.

Comment: How can you store a number formatted as hexedecimal in a numeric variable? Hexadecimals can contain letters. What will happen if the hex value is 0xFF?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The length is hex `15` which is decimal `21`. Neither of those interpretations is stored in the byte, which is binary `10101`. The value of the 3rd byte is `15` if you print it with `%X` and `21` if you print it with `%d`. They are the *same value*.

Comment: Same what @WeatherVane wrote... why it matters if the value is in hex or dec as long it is the correct value?

Comment: The problem is i need the value of <0x15> as it represents an important variable in the algorithm.
But it's written as 21, how can i convert it to 15?

Comment: 21 *is* the decimal value. Maybe you want to know how to format the number as hex?

Comment: Why do you need to? It's the *same value*.

Comment: Yes, i've phrased this question terribly...

Comment: Do you understand it can not be an `int`? Hexadecimal values have letters while `int` can only store a set of bits. There is no such thing as a variable to store hexadecimal value. You need to interpret it in a string.

Comment: @WeatherVane When i store it in an integer i get the value of 21, and then send it to other parts of the algorithm i run into a problem as the expected value is 15

Comment: @dedecos did you understand that **three bytes** are received, not the text as presented in the question to explain the format?

Comment: @Dejan The expected value should not be 15. 15 is 15. It's 0b1111. 15 is not 0x15. Anything that should expect 0x15, but expects 15, is incorrect.

Comment: Yes @WeatherVane but he is implying that he wants the hexadecimal format of the decimal value 21 (which is 15) but it can't be done without using a alphanumeric representation of the value.

Comment: *"It's written as 21"*. Where? I think you need to post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem.

Comment: @dedecos You're right, i've solved it by sprintf-ing it with %x into a string and then using strtol, but it's ugly and i'm hoping i find a better solution.

Comment: Ok @Dejan if your question is answered consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: Unrelated to you question, you should never use `char` for storing raw data bytes, because it has various problems with poorly-defined signedness that in turn tend to lead to subtle bugs. Instead, always use `uint8_t` from stdint.h.

Comment: Anyway, it isn't clear if you expect the data to be BCD, or if you simply don't know how computers/UART store data. As it stands now either of the posted answers could be correct, but we don't know which one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `int x` that contains 8 bits that represent a number using [natural packed binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), they can be converted to the number with:

```
int y = x/16*10 + x%16;
```

`x/16` produces the high four bits, and then multiplying by ten scales them to the tens position. `x%16` produces the low four bits. They are kept in the ones position and added to the tens.